# PHP Dynamic insert by multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

```
Array ( 
    [modo_prep] => 
    [modo_serv] => 
    [id_prod_comp] => 18 
    [id_ingrediente] => 
    Array ( 
    [0] => 16 
    [1] => 17 
    [2] => 18 
        ) 
    [qtd] => Array ( 
    [0] => 10 
    [1] => 100 
    [2] => 1000 
        ) 
    [rend_kg] => Array ( 
    [0] => 20 
    [1] => 200 
    [2] => 2000 
        ) 
    [submit] => Guardar 
    [id_receita] => 0 
)
```

(post array) and need to be dynamic insert, so i want to do a universal post function to insert. 
with simple array its ok 2 dimensoions there is a problem because i cannot match 1st value of N and so on, i need to be each array but same position each one sub-arrays to put in insert sentence.

so example: i have 1 row product, dinamic jquery (id_product[]) and i dont want to put the keys i want the script read all post data and put simple array in one table and the other N in other mysql table and each loop create 1 record with same key of each N sub arrays. row 1 has 3 fields it comes with 3 arrays, each row but if i put N i need to deal with that.

Code:

```
<?
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ERROR);
if($_POST['submit'] == TRUE){

$table  = 'receitas';
$table2  = 'receitas_componentes';
$element1 = array();

$element3 = array();

$i=0;
    foreach ($_POST as $key =>$valor){
   if( $key != 'submit'){
       if( !is_array($valor )){
    $element1[$key] = $valor;

    $colnames = "`".implode("`, `", array_keys($element1))."`";
$colvals = "'".implode("', '", $element1)."'";


$query_element1="INSERT INTO `".$table."` (".$colnames.") VALUES (".$colvals.")";
   }else{

//echo $colvals = "'".implode("', '", $element1)."'";


$count = sizeof($valor);
extract_1_array($valor,0);

//else
    }

 //not submit  
 }



}  

//echo $query_element1;
//mysql_query($query_element1);

$id_receita= mysql_insert_id(); 

//$_POST['id_receita']=$id_receita;



      }




function extract_1_array($valor, $increment){

    $i=0;

    foreach ($valor as $key2 => $ingredientes){


    $subarray[$i] .=$ingredientes ;

    $i++;

    }
    echo $subarray[$i]; echo("<br>");
    //$var10= implode($subarray[0]);

}
    //echo  $var10;



?>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
blank
```

Comment: What you did try so far? Post your code.

Comment: function extract_1_array($valor, $increment){
 
$subarray= at
 foreach ($valor as $key2 => $ingredientes){
 
  $$key2 = $ingredientes;
  = array($key2 =>$ingredientes);
 
 }print_r($subarray[$increment]); 
}
 i am calling that one in other loop

Comment: edit your question with the code.

Comment: http://teste.solucoes.pt/codeshare.txt

Comment: I have solved the problem, my issue is in my html treatment of the values and not in php need to put levels[level][] in name to join arrays same row.